# What is the difference of main and master branch?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I am currently learning **git** and **github**. So, I made a new repository for my e-commerce project. As I found that I can commmit and sync changes using the **vscode** and I made commits and synced the changes from there. But If I did from there I says I am working on **main** branch.

I want to know the difference of the main and master branch in github. Do we miss some features in **main** branch that is in **master** branch?

Comment: They are conceptually the same thing. The convention just changed: previously the primary branch was called `master` and for newer repository that defaults to `main`. You should only ever have one of those in a single repository (nothing breaks if you have both, but it's unlikely to be intentional).

Comment: Same difference between your `foo` and `bar` variables in any language: they're just different identifiers.

Answer (score 9):

There is no functional difference in and of itself. Any difference for your workflow stems from the way you use and design your repo.

The git documentation states in the options for [git init](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init) (i.e. creating a new repo):

> --initial-branch=
>
> Use the specified name for the initial branch in the newly created repository. If not specified, fall back to the default name (currently **master**, but this is subject to change in the future; the name can be customized via the init.defaultBranch configuration variable).

(Emphasis mine)